# json_decode($string, true)

Tags: php, json

Дано:

```
<?php

$str = '{"1013":[{"type":6,"value":"The hormone hCG is released when you conceive, and may alter your mood."},{"type":8,"value":"Make sure you log your data to find a pattern between your symptoms, and whether or not you conceived."},{"type":7,"value":"You are approaching the end of your menstrual cycle and of the luteal phase. Progesterone will continue to be produced until the corpus luteum breaks down about 14 days after ovulation (it does not break down if an embryo implants). At this point, your uterine lining is of no use so your period will begin."}]}';
echo $str;
echo "<br><br>";
```

Используя `$json = json_decode($string, true)` нужно вывести на экран данные касательно только `{"type":8, "value"}`.
Как это правильно сделать? Пожалуйста подскажите! Особых идей нет, kак вариант:

```
<?php

$str = '{"1013":[{"type":6,"value":"The hormone hCG is released when you conceive, and may alter your mood."},{"type":8,"value":"Make sure you log your data to find a pattern between your symptoms, and whether or not you conceived."},{"type":7,"value":"You are approaching the end of your menstrual cycle and of the luteal phase. Progesterone will continue to be produced until the corpus luteum breaks down about 14 days after ovulation (it does not break down if an embryo implants). At this point, your uterine lining is of no use so your period will begin."}]}';
echo $str;
echo "<br><br>";

$element1 = array();
$element1["type"] = 6;
$element1["value"] = "The hormone hCG is released when you conceive, and may alter your mood.";

$element2 = array();
$element2["type"] = 8;
$element2["value"] = "Make sure you log your data to find a pattern between your symptoms, and whether or not you conceived.";

$element3 = array();
$element3["type"] = 7;
$element3["value"] = "You are approaching the end of your menstrual cycle and of the luteal phase. Progesterone will continue to be produced until the corpus luteum breaks down about 14 days after ovulation (it does not break down if an embryo implants). At this point, your uterine lining is of no use so your period will begin.";

$elements = array();
$elements[0] = $element1;
$elements[1] = $element2;
$elements[2] = $element3;

$final = array();
$final[1013] = $elements;

$json = json_decode($final, true);
echo $json;
```

Comment: Если ответ вас устроил - примите его (отметьте галочкой). Если нет - напишите комментарий, предворив его @RussCoder , чтобы я получил уведомление (можно под моим ответом или под вопросом)

Comment: Привет. Рад, что вы задали первый конкретный вопрос и даже ответ получили. =) Тут не принято писать «Спасибо» в виде ответа. Вместо этого, если ответ вам помог, примите его — там есть галочка слева от ответа.

Comment: Если вам нужны уточнения, вы можете задавать вопросы в комментариях под своим сообщением. Когда будет немного больше репутации, станет можно комментировать любое сообщение.

Comment: Последнее: похоже, вы каждый раз задаете вопросы с незарегистрированного аккаунта. Предлагаю вам зарегистрироваться, тогда вы сможете получать уведомления об ответах и повышать свою репутацию, а вместе с ней и возмжности на сайте.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$json = json_decode($string, true); // раскодировать в виде ассоциативного массива
foreach($json['1013'] as $elem) {
    echo $elem['type'], " ", $elem['value'];
}
```

Просто пройтись по массиву в поле `'1013'`.

```
{  
"1013":
[{"type":6,"value":"The hormone hCG is released when you conceive, and may alter your mood."}, 
{"type":8,"value":"Make sure you log your data to find a pattern between your symptoms, and whether or not you conceived."},
{"type":7,"value":"You are approaching the end of your menstrual cycle and of the luteal phase. Progesterone will continue to be produced until the corpus luteum breaks down about 14 days after ovulation (it does not break down if an embryo implants). At this point, your uterine lining is of no use so your period will begin."}]
}
```

Запись предстваляет собой объект с 1 полем `'1013'`, в этом поле лежит массив из 3 объектов, каждый из которых состоит из поля `'type'` и `'value'`.

`json_decode($string, true);` -раскодирует json, второй аргумент означает, что не в виде объекта, а в виде ассоциативного массива. 
Вот и получается, что мы проходим по массиву, хранящемуся в 1м поле